# How can I create an Amazon Machine Image from a large VMDK file?

Tags: linux, amazon-ami, vmware-vmdk

I am in the process of attempting to create an Amazon Machine Image from a large (160 GB) VMDK disk image of a virtual machine running Linux; however, I keep running up against notices about a 10 GB limit for AMIs. Is there a way to upload large images or is the limit firm enough that I'm better off creating the image in the cloud?

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#What_is_VM_Import_Export

Comment: @Chopper3 - Doesn't support Linux, I'll add that to the question so that it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* an AMI unless you're spooling multiple copies of an environment.

You should be able to launch a worker instance, mount a volume large enough and `dd` your disk image (Not the VMDK, but a `dd`'d clone ) to the volume.

Then, you can launch a new instance and mount the volume you just `dd`'d to as the root.

It should work in theory, but in practice I've never done it. I'd assume you'll want to make sure your network is set for DHCP before you make the image. I'm also uncertain of any drivers that may be required...

Comment: Going to be spooling multiple copies so that likely wouldn't work.